# Find and replace a html element with an specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something like this HTML code:

`<ul>

    <li><a href="#">21</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>

</ul>`

And I want to make a Jquery code that add class to the link with the gave text (notice that have to be exactly the text).
For example, if I call `Method(1, "replaced text")` then this has to be the HTML result:

`<ul>

    <li><a href="#">21</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>

    <li><a class="myclass" href="#">1</a>replaced text</li>

    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>

</ul>`

Comment: I can't do this with the contains jquery selector

Comment: `:contains` matches more than *exactly the text*, though.

Comment: here, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5uy2/1/) for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to match the element, then chain [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) into [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("li > a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "1";
}).addClass("myclass").after("replaced text");
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
function someName(niddle, new_text)
{
    $('ul a').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == niddle){
            $(this).addClass('myclass');
            $(this).after(new_text);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers [a selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for that

```
$('a:contains(10)').addClass('myclass');
```

Try the code at

http://jsfiddle.net/8zmus/

Comment: Doesn't work with `$('a:contains(1)').addClass('myclass');` cite: "Notice that have to be exactly the text"

Comment: right. didn't understand the "notice that have to be exactly the text". or maby it wasn't there when i read the question?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't provide a selector for "this exact text", but it's easy to write (laaeftr). You can also use a more flexible "matches" selector, which matches a text against a regular expression (given without delimiters):

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    matches: function (el, index, m) {  
        var s = new RegExp(m[3]);
        return s.test($(el).text());
    }  
});
```

Once we've got that, the rest is easy:

```
$("li > a:matches(^10$)").addClass("foo")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/am7rY/